# Exporting pdf links at specific page in LaTeX

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, pdf-tools

In my org document:

> [[pdf:~/path/to/my/document.pdf::102][quote]]

In my LaTeX export I get:

> \href{file:///path/to/my/document.pdf}{quote}

How can I fix this?

Edit: A fix should correctly expand the link and include the page

> \href[page=102]{absolute/path/to/my/document.pdf}{quote}

Comment: What counts as a fix?  Correct expansion of the path?

Comment: I presume you mean `[[file:~/path/to/document.pdf::102][quote]]`: AFAIK, there is no `pdf` link in Org mode. Also, AFAIK you can target a specific page in a PDF document through a link like `file:///path/to/document.pdf#page=4` but you cannot target a specific line number, so there is a mismatch between the two different specifications.